# JavaScript using isNaN to validate returns NaN

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, for-loop

I have some code here that will make validations of whether or not the input from a text box is NOT an empty string and isNaN. When i do these validations on amounts entered, i would like it to add them up.. however when a user does not enter anything in one or more amount fields the program should just add entered fields. But instead i get NaN showing in the total field.

link to full code: http://jsfiddle.net/KxNqQ/

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculateBills = function () {

var myErrorFlag = "N";

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    AmountNumber = 'amount' + i;
    AmountValue = $(AmountNumber).value;

    if (AmountValue != "" && isNaN(AmountValue)) {
        $(AmountNumber).style.color = "red";
        myErrorFlag = "Y";
    } else {
        $(AmountNumber).style.color = "black";
        myErrorFlag = "N";
    }


}

if (myErrorFlag != "Y") {
    var Amount = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        Amount += parseInt($('amount' + i).value,10);
    }
    $('total').value = Amount;
    }

   }
var clearFields = function () {

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    itemName = 'item' + i;
    $(itemName).value = "";
}
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    amountName = 'amount' + i;
    $(amountName).value = "";
}
$('total').value = "";


}
window.onload = function () {
$("clearfields").onclick = clearFields;
$("addbills").onclick = calculateBills;
}
```

Comment: You are using global variables – don't do that, it's bad and dangerous. Also, your `myErrorFlag` will be `"N"` as long as the last field was okay. Any information about previous fields is overwritten. Lastly, your code contains no logic for skipping fields that haven't been filled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got your requirements a little bit confused, or at the very least I was confused by them. So in order to answer your question, I'm going to rephrase the requirements so I understand them better. This is a useful exercise that I try to do when I'm not 100% sure of the requirements; if I can't get the requirements right, what's to say I'll get the code right?

So the requirements – as I understand them – are:

```
Given each amount input
When the input has a value
And that value is a number
Then add the value to the total
And make the input color black
But if the input does not have a value
Or that value is not a number
Then make the input color red
```

Going through your code, I can see a number of problems with it. First, I noticed that both `AmountNumber` and `AmountValue` are global variables, because they were not declared local with the [var keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). So before fixing our code, let's change that. Let's also change the variable names to something that more accurately describe what they are, hopefully making the code easier to understand:

```
var input = $('amount' + i);
var value = input.value;
```

Now, note that I chose to store the element in the `input` variable. This is so we don't have to look it up multiple times within the loop. Looking things up in the DOM can be expensive so we'll want to keep it to a minimum. There are other was to look up elements as well, such as [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll); those are left as an exercise for the reader to research and evaluate.

Next, in each iteration of the loop, you check that `AmountValue` is *not* a string and simultaneously is *not* a number:

```
if (AmountValue != "" && isNaN(AmountValue)) {
```

This will be true so long as `AmountValue` is [truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) (which is the case for non-empty strings) and so long as `isNaN` thinks it's a number (which is the case for strings that contain numbers.) It really is rather confusing; if I understand your code correctly this clause is there to check for invalid input and if it is true should mark the input field red and set a flag. I.e. this is the *but* clause in the aforementioned requirements.

Let's rewrite this to be the *when* clause instead, we'll take care of the *but* later. Before we do that, let's look at the `myErrorFlag`. It's used – I think – to see whether all input is well formed and in that case, add it all up. Well, validation and summation can be done in one fell swoop, so let's get rid of the flag and sum the values while validating them. So we replace `myErrorFlag` with a `total` variable:

```
var total = 0;
```

Now, let's get back to our clause. The requirements say:

```
When the input has a value
And that value is a number
Then add the value to the total
```

In code, that should look something like this:

```
if (value && !isNaN(value)) {
  total += parseInt(value, 10);
  input.style.color = 'black';
}
```

There are a couple of things going on here. For one, the if statement has been turned on its head a bit from what it was. It first checks to see that `value` is [truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/), then that it is a number. The second check can be a bit tricky to read, because it is essentially a double negation; in english it reads "is not not a number", i.e. "is a number". I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out whether there's a more easily understood way of writing this check.

Now what about the *but* clause in our requirements?

```
But if the input does not have a value
Or that value is not a number
Then make the input color red
```

Well, it's essentially the inverse of our previous statement, so let's simply add an `else` clause:

```
else {
  input.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Because the requirements doesn't mention the `total` variable in this clause, it is simply ignored and doesn't show up in the end result.

Adding it all up (no pun intended) [the code – with comments – looks like this](http://jsbin.com/OfoTAwe/2/edit):

```
var calculateBills = function () {
  var total = 0;

  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    // Given each amount input
    var input = $('amount' + i);
    var value = input.value;

    if (value && !isNaN(value)) {
      // When the input has a value
      // And that value is a number
      // Then add the value to the total
      total += parseInt(value, 10);

      // And make the input color black
      input.style.color = 'black';
    } else {
      // But if the input does not have a value
      // Or that value is not a number
      // Then make the input color red
      input.style.color = 'red';
    }
  }

  $('total').value = total;
};
```

---

There are more things that could be learned from this to make for better code. For instance, this code will break if the number of inputs change, or if their id names change. This is because they are selected specifically by their IDs and as such, if those change then this code will no longer function.

Another potential issue is that we're setting inline styles on the inputs as we loop over them. This means that in order to keep this code up to date with the styling of the site, it'll have to change. Generally, mixing styling and functionality like this is not a good idea and should be avoided. One way of doing so is to use class names instead, and toggle these on and off. Incidentally, this could also help the previous problem I mentioned.

There are other problems as well, but we'll leave those for another day. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thank you for the in-depth answer you have provided. This actually is exactly how it is supposed to function.. I thank you for the time you put in for this very descriptive answer. This is a small project that is for learning. This isn't some website that is going to be published but i do appreciate all the comments and facts you have stated. Thank you @macke

Comment: I figured it was for learning, that's why I took the time. An answer that just solves the problem won't teach you anything, so I hoped this would. I'm glad it was useful to you! Also, the way I wrote the requirements is actually somewhat like what you'd do in Behavior Driven Development, often BDD for short; it may be a useful topic to delve into at some point in the future. For now, my best tip is to just keep hacking at things – you'll get the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var calculateBills = function () {
    var Amount = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        var AmountElement = $('amount' + i),
            AmountValue = AmountElement.value;
        if (AmountValue != "" && !isNaN(AmountValue)) {
            AmountElement.style.color = "red";
            Amount += parseInt(AmountValue,10);
        } else {
            AmountElement.style.color = "";
        }
    }
    $('total').value = Amount;
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxNqQ/3/)

Anyway, instead of using elements with id like `id="amount1"`, `id="amount2"`, `id="amount3"`, etc., you could use classes (e.g `class="amount"`) and get them with `.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Thank you for looking at my code, I have not learned the .getElementByClassName. @oriol